# Formatting Column in Content Type Hub Not Available Anymore?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, column-formatting

I feel like I am going crazy, but 6 months ago (ish), I created a site column in my Content Type Hub. Right there while I was creating the column, I formatted it. Because at that point you could format a column when you create it. Then I added the column to a content type, and all the libraries where that content type was published to received the column, with the formatting.

But now...something changed?
Because I can't format a column that I create in the CT Hub anymore...I can create a column. But then if I want to format it I need to do that in the local document library. Which is ridiculous. Can anyone confirm this? Or am I missing something big?

TL;DR: 
Is it possible to format a column in the Content Type Hub, so that I can include it in a Content Type, and inherit the column (formatted) in all my Document Libraries?

Comment: I have also observed the same behavior in our tenant. I am not able to add JSON formatting to a site column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATE

I've just heard back from the engineering team working on this issue. They identified the issue as a regression and they have now rolled out the fix across production.

You posting this issue here helped solve it for everyone! Thank you!

---

### Original Answer

This looks to be an issue not specific to the Content Type Hub. Up until recently you could apply formats using the Site Column or Field Settings screen for a column. That format box is missing right now for all but the following field types:

- Person
- Lookup
- External Data
- Managed Meta Data

You can see it working for a Person Site Column in my Content Type Hub:
[image]

I can confirm that the format box is not showing when I select other field types from the list above.

This is definitely a regression and I'm seeing it in both Targeted and Standard Release tenants. I'll reach out to a few people that might know how to help, but if you can open a support ticket this is much more likely to get addressed.

Answer (score 1):

The Column Formatting feature has been removed from classic experience column settings in SharePoint Online (and does not apply to classic experience, per my test).

Currently we could only set the column formatting via clicking a column heading, select **Column settings** from the menu, and then click **Format this column**.

Reference:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/column-formatting-1f927342-2bed-4745-b727-ff8b7ff96b22

Comment: does that mean this is 'By design' and we have lost this functionality permanently now?

Comment: Yes, it's by design and as Chriskent said, only limited column types have column formatting in Content Type Hub.

Comment: This was identified as a bug and has now been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, how disappointing. 
Looks like another feature that has been purposely removed.

If you want to get it back, and be able to create and format columns in your content type hub, and publish them to other sites vote on the uservoice here:
https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/286611-office-365-groups/suggestions/40558972-re-enable-column-formatting-in-content-type-hub

Comment: This was not purposely removed. It was a regression that has now been addressed. Yay!